# Is there any way to make a python program stop at any point in execution with a keyboard command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am creating a CLI choose your own adventure game for a school assignment in Python 3.8.3. I have the code structured like this:

```
While True:
    if room=='a room':
        (code for the room, ending with a change of rooms)
    elif room=='another room':
        (code for the room, ending with a change of rooms)
    etc.
```

I want to be able to restart my program at any point using ctrl+r

I have tried using Pygame's event list, but this doesn't work for me, as I cannot check this while the other stuff in the program is running. I guess I need something in python that can run at the same time as the main program, continually checking for an input of <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd>

I've heard that there is an async keyword that could maybe do this, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Do you *really* need to be able to restart at *any* point? Would it suffice to be able to restart at the beginning of any iteration of the `while` loop? Because that would be a *lot* easier, and if you look at how real-world games actually work, they tend to be more like that.

Comment: It's quite easy to read a Control-r, but I would strongly urge you against it. Asking your program's user to enter Control sequences is asking for trouble because some of the Control sequences will interrupt your program and there is nothing you can do in python to prevent it. Cortrol-C, for example. A typo by your user can end your code. If you are set on using Control-r, look into the keyboard functions offered under msvcrt and the kbfunct. As with many things in python, there are more than one ways to get it done.